# Asp.net: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'test' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created an Imagebutton with an **onclientclick()** method, but when i push the button the error **Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'test' is undefined** appears.

Here is the complete code code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Librerian_ReviewHistory.aspx.cs"
        Inherits="Library.Librerian_ReviewHistory" MasterPageFile="../user.Master" %>



<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <script type="text/javascript">

       function test()
       {

           window.open.('ShowUsers.aspx',null,'scrollbars=1,width=600,HEIGHT=400');

       }


    </script>


    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
        </p>

            <p>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Username" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                    CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Text="Categories" ValidationGroup="v1"
                    ImageUrl="~/Account/user1.jpg" OnClientClick="test();" />
            </p>


    </fieldset>


</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Try to write js function in header section. Also there is dot(.) after window.open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running your code everything seems to be alright. just remove extra dot(.) after window.open function. Your function will run smoothly.